# Why was the TV show ' The River' cancelled?

Tags: cancellation, the-river

There used to be this serial called [*The River*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_River_(U.S._TV_series)) (2012) where the storyline was of a family (mother and son) searching for their father or husband in the Amazon with a series of suspense and new discoveries. It was going really good but then suddenly they stopped shooting further seasons. Does anyone have an update on this?

Comment: I corrected the name in the title, there is another series called just "River" https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4258440/

Comment: @Luciano oops I missed to fix the title, I need to read the synopsis of three shows with giver name to even get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Deadline](https://deadline.com/2012/03/netflix-eyes-abc-drama-series-the-river-247479/) it was due to ratings:

> The River never got traction on ABC, finishing its midseason run with a 1.4 18-49 rating for its finale Tuesday.

Also from [TV Series Finale](https://tvseriesfinale.com/tv-show/the-river-cancelled-season-two-22983/)

> The TV series had an okay premiere, registering a 2.6 rating in the 18-49 demographic with 8.35 million viewers. Unfortunately later episodes didn’t do nearly as well and towards the end of its short season it went as low as a 1.3 in the demo with 4.09 million.
>
> On our [ABC Ratings Report Card](https://tvseriesfinale.com/tv-show/abc-2011-2012-ratings/), which measures the relative success of
>   shows on the network, The River has a “D” grade and is one of the
>   lowest-rated shows on ABC this season. It’s no surprise that the
>   network has cancelled it.
>
> While you won’t see a second season ABC, there’s still a glimmer of
>   hope that Netflix could pick it up. The movie rental/streaming service
>   had preliminary discussions with ABC Studios about possibly picking up
>   the show if ABC ended up canning it.

But it's been so long and no news from Netflix either about renewal.